# how to investigate diff between theguardian.com and tehguardian.com

Tags: ip, domain

One website is `the....com` the other is `teh....com`. They display the same content.

The whois data is radically different. Ping reports different IPs.

TheGuardian.com hasn't responded to my request for clarification.

How can I investigate the maliciousness, if any?

Comment: To investigate potential maliciousness, you investigate the suspect site. I'm not sure what you are asking. All you have said is "I found a site that mirrors another. The domains are owned by different parties." There are many reason why this could be.

Comment: If your question is "can you investigate for me" then that question is off-topic (we don't investigate). If you want to know *how* to investigate, then we need more details.

Answer (score 2):

#### How can I investigate the maliciousness, if any?

It is not malicious, the tehguardian.com can be considered as a parody of the guardian.com.

> They display the same content.

If you look very closely you will see the are **not** identical.

**Some Background**

The Guardian Newspaper is well known for containing for containing spelling mistakes and grammatical errors - it had the nickname The [Grauniad](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Grauniad) as a result:

> Deliberate misspelling of Guardian, coined by the UK satirical magazine Private Eye. Refers to the fact that in earlier years the Guardian newspaper was well-known for typographical errors.

Someone ([stef](http://writing.makeshift.io/contributors/stef)) then thought it would be funny to produce a spoof website that was a copy of the The Guardian website but with deliberately inserted mistakes.

> I’ve made a little hack called TehGuardian.com — it inserts random
>   grammar and punctuation mistakes into TheGuardian.com. Can you spot
>   the mistakes?
>
> You may remember that in 2013 The Guardian rebranded online as The
>   Guardian. No, I thought it was a bit odd too. Something to do with
>   guardian.co.uk changing to theguardian.com
>
> Now, if you saw that happening, what would your immediate reaction be?
>
> Of course. Same here. I went to my usual domain registrar site, and
>   whacked in thegrauniad.com but obviously they’d thought of that.
>
> So I typed in “tehguardian.com”, “teh” being the proper way to spell
>   “the” on the internet, and gosh. Would you look at that? Somehow
>   nobody had thought to buy it. And I use one of those one-click domain
>   registrars. And I was feeling mischevious. And…
>
> ...
>
> **TehGuardian.com**
>
> It’s the Guardian website as we know and love. But every single
>   article page has up to five grammatical errors introduced into it.
>
> So if you make the mistake of typing in “teh” instead of “the” when
>   you try to reach the Guardian, you’ll also receive a slightly glitchy
>   version back.
>
> It’s quite subtle. Probably my subtlest [hack](http://stef.io/hacks) yet.
>
> Every article that you read via tehguardian.com is exactly the same as
>   an article on theguardian.com except that I have introduced incorrect
>   Oxford commas, instances of “s’s” where it should be “s’”, swapped
>   “they’re” for “their” and a handful of other grammar-pedant-traps.

Source [Teh Guardian FTW!!!1!](http://writing.makeshift.io/pieces/tehguardian)

Comment: tehguardian.com is missing the banner ads, but if you use the intra-site search, the results begin with a set of ads whose URLs contain teh 'referrer' tokens, such as `https://www.googleadservices.com/.........&res_url=https‌​://www.tehguar‌​dian.com/us/trav‌​el&rurl=http://tehguardian.com.........`

Comment: @user567324 I use uBlock Origin so I don't see the ads :)